# vi: move a line by 4 bytes

Tags: shell, vi

I want to move a line by 4 bytes using vi editor. What command should I use?

I tried ">>" and it does move but it moves by 8 bytes..

Comment: Why are you making measurements in "bytes" in a text editor?  Text is by the "character" or "glyph".

Comment: Why are you manually inserting space. Are you trying to format code. If so there are probably better ways. If you could explain what you are trying to achieve at a higher level that may be more useful.

Answer (score 11):

Default `shiftwidth` in `vi` is `8` spaces, from `:help shiftwidth`:

```
'shiftwidth' 'sw'       number  (default 8)
                        local to buffer
        Number of spaces to use for each step of (auto)indent.  Used for
        'cindent', >>, <<, etc.
```

So you should set `shiftwidth` to `4`:

```
set shiftwidth=4
```

Add above line to `.exrc` file to make it persistence.

Answer (score 6):

In normal mode, type `4I` then press **space** and then **escape**.

This will insert 4 spaces at the beginning of the line and move the line to the right. I assume this is what you want, since you mentioned that **>>** almost works for you.

Comment: When you are in the middle of the line, this solution works with a slight modification: use 4I (capital-i) for inserting the spaces at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

When you are familiar with sed, you can also try sed-like commands.
Suppose you just added an if statement and want to indent the lines until the next }.
Then try

```
:.,/}/-1 s/^/    /
```